# Javadoc only one class in a package using Ant

Tags: java, javadoc, ant

I am using apache ant to generate javadoc for my project. I have a number of classes in one of my packages and I only want to show one. How do I do this? Here is my current code.

```
<javadoc
    sourcepath="jig-engine/src"
    destdir="${target.path}/docs/javadoc/"
    packagenames="jig.engine.util.Vector2D" >
</javadoc>
```

(simplified for clarity)

Comment: If a class is private, documentation will not be generated. My I ask why you don't want to generate documentation for these classes? If it's because you don't want people accessing them, make them protected or private or change how they are accessed. Security by obscurity doesn't work.

Comment: +1 to Malfist; I can think of no circumstances in which limiting the Javadocs is the best solution to a problem (in my experience, at least).

Comment: How about if you are making a curriculum for beginning java students and don't want them confused by classes they don't need for the assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the sourcefiles parameter instead of sourcepath:

```
<javadoc
    sourcefiles="jig-engine/src/path/to/your/file.java"
    destdir="${target.path}/docs/javadoc/">
</javadoc>
```

Comment: This only works if file.java is not dependent on other files.  I tried this and got javadoc errors because `file.java` referenced code in a different file that wasn't listed.  Is there a way to get javadoc to look at several files, but generate code for just one of them (without restricting the visibility of the other classes)?